# Xcode 5 Is it possible to change the font and size on the storyboard?

Tags: fonts, ios7, uilabel, xcode5, font-size

In Xcode 5 is it possible to change the font and size on the storyboard?
If I select a UILabel or button etc, and look in the inspector pane to the right, I am unable to find a way of changing the font type and size?

I have found the Edit Menu > Format > Font, and can increase a font size, but have to keep doing this once at a time, rather than being able to edit the number, but can see no way of changing font or colour etc?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can change the font (choosing from those in Xcode) the size of the font and color, everything from the storyboard

check this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, I have been searching for a long time for that, and turned out that the Label Properties within the attribute inspector were hidden. It was seeing your screenshot that made me realise my view was different, and thus I clicked around and it appeared. It is a pity you have to hover to where the show/hide button is to actually see the button appear!

Comment: Agree! Actually, from UX is incorrectly designed: it should be either a expandable section of a tree-view, or always visible in the Inspector. Those editable tooltips are usually a very bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

Open the Utilities Panel on the right and view the Attributes inspector by using the shortcut key ⌘⌥4 or selecting the shield looking icon at the top of the panel, and when a UILabel, UIButton, or other object containing the desired attributes (Font, color, etc) will show in the inspector window on the right.

By clicking on the icon inside of the "Font" attribute you bring up additional options including the font style, family, and size. You can also select one of the new Dynamic Type styles (Body, Caption, Headline, etc) in this attribute inspector panel.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, I have been searching for a long time for that, and turned out that the Label Properties within the attribute inspector were hidden. It was seeing your screenshot that made me realise my view was different, and thus I clicked around and it appeared. It is a pity you have to hover to where the show/hide button is to actually see the button appear!